# Xcode error: "team is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program xcode distribute"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have in my Xcode preferences my Apple Developer Program account that is the owner of an organization.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pw5s.png)

When I want to upload the app to the App Store Connect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA6uj.png)

It appears this error:

"team " My personal Team" is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program xcode distribute"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPzak.png)

I already have an app created in App store connect and its identifier. What is the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't link to external images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have correct account selected in the ‘Signing & Capabilities’ section in your project?

I believe you are building archive using the personal team dev account selected.

Comment: Where can I see that?

Comment: Click on your project root file in xcode then select your app target then under the ‘Signing & Capabilities’ section find ‘Team’ and select your dev account there.

Comment: Yes, it was because of that. Thanks a lot.